# TypeScript arrow functions double return

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have been reading some React code written in TS and I've come across this code:

```
const loggedInRequired = () => (
    toState: State,
    fromState: State,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    done: any
) => {
    // userIsLoggedIn can be whatever you need it to be
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // redirect to signin page if the user isn't logged in
      done({ redirect: { name: Routes.Login } });
      return false;
    }
  };
```

I want to know what this specific part means:

```
() => (someParam: someType, someOtherParam: someType) => { someCodeHere }
```

what does the part in between second group of parenthesis represent ? It looks like an interface but I can't see the logic behind it, `done` is obviously a function because we call it later in the code, but I can't understand the general meaning of this code.

**EDIT**

It's just me being retarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function (that starts at `() =>`) that returns another function (the other function starting at `(toState: State, fromState: State,done: any ) =>`).

When you call `loggedInRequired` the result will be a function

```
const loggedInRequiredResult = loggedInRequired (); // will be a (toState: any, fromState: any, done: any) => boolean
const finalResult = loggedInRequiredResult (null, null, null) // will be a boolean
```

Comment: Dear God, I feel so retarded, lack of sleep or something, it's not my fault really :D :D :D